# Faster way/shortcut of scaling images in Adobe Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm trying to find out if there is a faster way to complete repetitve actions in Indesign - every time I add a new image, I need to resize it to either 5.25% or 3.5%, which atm means I am clicking through Transform, etc., hundreds of times an hour. I've looked into editing the shortcuts but there doesn't seem to be an option for custom percentages.

Surely there must be a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script to scale any selected image to 5.25%:

```
var scale = 5.25;
var img = (app.selection.length > 0) ? app.selection[0] : exit();
try { img = img.graphics[0] } catch(e) {};
img.horizontalScale = img.verticalScale = scale;
img.parent.fit(FitOptions.FRAME_TO_CONTENT);
```

You can assign any shortcuts to any scripts via

[image]

I hope you can make the same way the second script to scale image to 3%.